# Vbscript is working fine in cmd prompt but not working in task scheduler

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript to get the records from Oracle database and need to get those records hourly basis.
When I ran the script from cmd , script is executing fine and getting records through email but when I schedule the same script from task scheduler ,  showing that task completed fine but records are not getting.
Do we need any permission to access the Oracle database from task scheduler
I have logged in the server with admin user.

Is there another way to schedule this script hourly basis.
Thanks in advance
Thanks
Chandrakiran

Answer (score 0):

Without some code I cannot help you much, I suspect this is an authentication issue however.

Note that the Task Scheduler does not take into account the currently logged in user when running, the script needs to authenticate itself with the database or set the "Run As" user in Task Scheduler if needed.